# STL for_each complaining about argument list

Tags: c++, stl, mem-fun

As part of a homework assignment, we are supposed to map the occurrence of each character in a map. Our function is supposed to use std::for_each and pass in the character to be evaluated.

My function is:

```
std::for_each(document_.begin(), 
              document_.end(), 
              std::mem_fun(&CharStatistics::fillMap));
```

`document_` is a `string`, and the fillMap function is defined like

```
void CharStatistics::fillMap(char ch)
{
    ch = tolower(ch);
    ++chars_.find(ch)->second;
}
```

`chars_` is declared as `std::map<char, unsigned int> chars_;`.

I figure this should work, but the compiler is complaining

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

Which confuses me, because when I look at the argument list

```
_Fn1=std::mem_fun1_t<void,CharStatistics,char>,
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<char>,
1>            _Result=void,
1>            _Ty=CharStatistics,
1>            _Arg=char,
1>            _InIt=std::_String_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
```

it looks fine to me. _Elem is a char and my function accepts a char. The iterator is nothing else than a `char *`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CharStatistics::fillMap` is not a function taking 1 argument. it's member function and so it has implicit first argument - pointer to class instance.

in code:

```
std::for_each(document_.begin(), 
              document_.end(), 
              std::mem_fun(&CharStatistics::fillMap));
```

`for_each` don't know on which instance you'd like to call `CharStatistics::fillMap`, you didn't specify it. you need to bind it with any CharStatistics instance, e.g.:

```
std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&CharStatistics::fillMap), &char_statistics_instance)
```

Answer (score 2):

document_ is a collection of characters?

But the function is a member function of CharStatistics! Presumably you are calling this from a member function of CharStatistics. In that case you can use boost::bind to solve it if that is allowed:

```
std::for_each( document_.begin(), document_.end(), 
     boost::bind( &CharStatistics::fillMap, this, _1 );
```

You could use std::bind1st on "this" which is more complex as you still need mem_fun

```
std::for_each( document_.begin(), document_.end(), 
      std::bind1st( std::mem_fun(&CharStatistics::fillMap), this ) );
```

which actually is horribly complex looking. That is why the new bind is so much better!

If you are not allowed to use boost::bind and you don't like the mem_fun solution, write your own functor that overloads operator() to take a char. Like this:

```
struct CharStatsFunctor
{
   typedef std::map< char, size_t > map_type;
   map_type & mapToFill;
   explicit CharStatsFunctor( map_type & m ) : mapToFill( m ) {}

   void operator()(char ch ) const
   {
       ++mapToFill[ ::tolower( ch ) ];
   }
};
```

In the loop call

```
std::for_each( document_.begin(), document_.end(), CharStatsFunctor( chars_ ) );
```

Note there is an error in your fillMap function. The solution I gave will work.

Comment: +1 … I almost exclusively use functors for such a task. They are just much more painless.

Answer (score 1):

If `CharStatistics::fillMap` is not a static member function, then you need to bind the call to an instance:

```
CharStatistics instance;
std::for_each(
     document_.begin(),
     document_.end(),
     std::bind1st(
         &CharStatistics::fillMap,
         &instance
     )
);
```

Further, if it's not a static member function, then it actually has two arguments. The first is the implicit `this` pointer, and the second is the `char`. So you have to bind two arguments, using `boost::bind` (or `std::bind` if you are on C++0x):

```
CharStatistics instance;
std::for_each(
     document_.begin(),
     document_.end(),
     boost::bind(
         &CharStatistics::fillMap,
         &instance,
         _1
     )
);
```

`for_each` should now see the `bind2nd` instance as a function object taking one argument (`_1`), and the instance will be passed automatically.

Comment: bind2nd won't do that, what you have written is a boost::bind or std::bind (new standard) construct. You will get a compiler error through because bind2nd only takes 2 parameters, a function and a parameter.

Comment: @CashCow: Ah balls, you're right. I always use `boost::bind`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is wrong is that your container has a value type `char`, and `for_each` expects a function which takes an argument of `char`, but `std::mem_fun(&CharStatistics::fillMap)` evaluates to a function object which takes an instance of `CharStatistics` (on which it will then call `fillMap`)

Why not simply change your function:

```
void CharStatistics::fillMap(std::string const& str)
{
  std::string::const_iterator it(str.begin()), end(str.end());
  for(; it != end; ++it)
    ++chars_.find(tolower(*it))->second;
}
```